# Tag Cloud Component doesn't support multilingual tags

Tags: sxa, multilingual, components

I am using `Sitecore 9.3` and working on `scaled environment`. First I have created tags with two versions English and Spanish for every tag like below "Sketch Tag"
[image]
I needed to tag content Page with two languages Spanish and English with using Tag Cloud Component. When I visited this Page on CD in English version, I found "Sketch Tag" appears in both the languages English and Spanish, the same way when I visited page in Spanish version. What is the way to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of OOTB Tag cloud (sxa 93), also noticed this was not corrected in sxa10 as well.

**Workaround :**
Clone the SXA **TagCloud** component and override **TryQueryFacet** from **TagCloudRepository** (*Sitecore.XA.Feature.Taxonomy.Repository.TagCloudRepository*) to make the query aware of the context Item language.

Example Code:

```
protected override bool TryQueryFacet(
      Item contextItem,
      string faceFieldName,
      out FacetResults query)
    {
        string contextItemId = contextItem.ID.ToSearchID();
        using (IProviderSearchContext providerSearchContext = this.PrepareSearchContext(this.MultisiteContext.GetSiteItem(contextItem)))
        {
            var expression = (Expression <Func<SearchResultItem, bool>>)PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
            expression = expression.And(i => i["_path"] == contextItemId);
            
            if(contextItem.IsFallback)
            {
                var fallbackLanguage = Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageFallbackManager.GetFallbackLanguage(Sitecore.Context.Language, Sitecore.Context.Database);
                expression = expression.And(i => i["_language"] == fallbackLanguage.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                expression = expression.And(i => i["_language"] == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
            }

            query = providerSearchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where<SearchResultItem>(
                (Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>>)expression).FacetOn<SearchResultItem, string>(
                (Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, string>>)(f => f[faceFieldName])
                ).GetFacets<SearchResultItem>();
        }
            
        return query != null;
    }
```

Notice the expression in snippet above which includes the context Item language and also handles the fallback.

Link to code gist here on the Controller and Repository:
https://gist.github.com/beyondsun/bd031960ebc9801450f469d85e42c105